# Vanilla JS | Invokable object that also contains property

Tags: javascript, json

I was asked in some assignment to do the following:

> fun4(): returns a object that can be invoked as a function. this object should also has a ‘k’ property with null value ( so fun4()() should do something)

The first part of the question is easy and understandable.
The second one is the issue for me.
How can I create an object in JS that can be invoked *and* accessed statically.

To simplify:
Can one create an object that behaves as follows:

```
> let o = CustomObject;
> o.k
< null
> o()
< //Some value returned here from the function
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks very straightforward to me...

```
let CustomObject = function(){ return "hello"; }
CustomObject.k = null;
```

This will pass your *Acceptance criteria*

Comment: This worked and I've wrote something like this before. Question is - Why can't I see this property (but I can access it) if I log it (through Chrome)?
@olivarra1

Comment: Because Chrome treats it as a function and gives you the "function" view. Try doing `console.log("%O", CustomObject)`, it will give you the "object" view. This code is also very useful for inspecting DOM elements (`console.log("%O", element)`)

Answer (score 1):

As for vanilla js, this is what you are looking for:

```
var fun4 = function () {
    let val = function () { console.log("hello"); };
    val.k = null;

    return val;
}


fun4()   // returns the function
fun4()() // logs 'hello'
fun4().k // returns null
```

Given one of your comments above, one thing to watch out for is your use of `let` and `var`. In this case, `var` could be used instead without any difference (when `val` falls out of scope when the function returns, the variable will be released for garbage collection). However, when you are running this within the console (and when not inside a function or other well-defined and isolated scope), variables created using `let` will get destroyed after every invocation -- in other words, whenever you press return. The way to demonstrate this is to compare these:

```
var test = function () {
    let x = 1;
    let x = 1;  // this will cause an immediate syntax error when the script is parsed;
}
```

On the other hand:

```
> let x = 1;
< undefined
> let x = 1; // In the console, this will not raise any error/exception
             // because the scope is cleared after the line above has
             // executed and returned
< undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see a 'k' property as below.

[image]